# How can I list in pairs on MySql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, list, search, key-value

"List in pairs the names of producers who are in the same city."

I need to return this on the search, but I quite didn't understand the pairs.

```
SELECT name
FROM producer 
ORDER BY city;
```

I did this, but is it really that simple?? Because I've never heard of pairs!!

Just wanna know if it is a "thing", you know?

Comment: It could be a `SELF JOIN` if they want **all** such pairs.

Comment: Yes, I kind of joined the same table??? It worked

Answer (score 0):

"pair" is not a database thing, it just has its ordinary English meaning -- a group of two things.

You need to join the table to itself to get producers in the same city:

```
SELECT p1.name AS producer1, p2.name AS producer2
FROM producers AS p1
JOIN producers AS p2 ON p1.city = p2.city AND p1.name < p2.name
```

The condition `p1.name < p2.name` ensures that you don't list a producer as paired with themself, and also that you don't list the same pair twice in opposite orders.

Comment: Ohhhhh, thanks. I got that!!